# How i can make disappeared my composant Menu when i'm not logged in?

Tags: reactjs

I wanna make disappeared my menu when my localStorage is not empty. For the moment it's working like that but i'm not using my useEffect so my app doesn't re-render directly.

What should i put on my UseEffect to have my page re-render directly ? thank you

```
function App() {
  

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.getItem("connexion");
  });

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {localStorage.getItem("connexion") != null ? <Menu /> : <div></div>}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/contact" component={MeContacter} />
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/" component={Connexion} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage isn't active so it won't trigger rerenders when it changes. You can use the `useEffect` hook when the component mounts to read from local storage and set some local state, but since this is technically derived state (*and since locatlStorage won't trigger rerenders*), you should just check localStorage each time `App` is rendered.

```
function App() {
  const showNav = !!localStorage.getItem("connexion");

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {showNav && <Menu />}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/contact" component={MeContacter} />
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/" component={Connexion} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

You *could* set up some localStorage polling to "listen" for updates.

```
function App() {
  const [showNav, setShowNav] = React.useState(
    () => !!localStorage.getItem("connexion")
  );

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setShowNav(!!localStorage.getItem("connexion"));
    }, 5000);
    return () =< clearInterval(timer);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        {showNav && <Menu />}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/contact" component={MeContacter} />
          <Route path="/Home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/" component={Connexion} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```